# Simple way to determine square-ness of signal?

Tags: signal-analysis, python

Not entirely sure if my term is correct. Feel free to edit title.

I have a lot of time series, where the data quality is determined by how linear each sub-sequence is. It doesn't matter if it jumps up or down. The most important thing is that each sub-sequence should be linear. The labels in the plot below reflect how "well-behaved" I think each series is with respect to squareness, just to illustrate my point.

I could probably map out every step with different change-point/step-finding algorithms, and then I'd have to fit each with a linear function.

But that's going to be a bit excessive (and maybe also slow), as I'd then have to evaluate and tune the change-point algorithm as well.

Is there a simpler way?

To clarify, the method must be able to reduce to a single value that I can determine automatically for thousands of traces, and then feed the values into subsequent steps.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([[70872, 0], [65951, 0], [66453, 0], [69058, 0], [67483, 0], [69352, 0], [66139, 0], [66042, 0], [65832, 0], [62785, 0], [66679, 0], [66407, 0], [65364, 0], [67065, 0], [62789, 0], [63566, 0], [62788, 0], [63823, 0], [66169, 0], [62814, 0], [64090, 0], [66121, 0], [66147, 0], [61734, 0], [64699, 0], [66599, 0], [64997, 0], [63778, 0], [62466, 0], [62359, 0], [68352, 0], [66454, 0], [65818, 0], [64873, 0], [67705, 0], [64548, 0], [65268, 0], [66382, 0], [63212, 0], [67100, 0], [64943, 0], [64848, 0], [64757, 0], [64170, 0], [65676, 0], [65108, 0], [66865, 0], [62515, 0], [62498, 0], [64160, 0], [65965, 0], [67430, 0], [67520, 0], [63422, 0], [62874, 0], [62442, 0], [62699, 0], [61413, 0], [63993, 0], [65945, 0], [63927, 0], [65711, 0], [68361, 0], [65237, 0], [65791, 0], [63750, 0], [62580, 0], [64105, 0], [63556, 0], [62507, 0], [65663, 0], [63952, 0], [66916, 0], [62010, 0], [64337, 0], [65831, 0], [65555, 0], [64249, 0], [62909, 0], [62050, 0], [63368, 0], [63323, 0], [64340, 0], [66999, 0], [65624, 0], [64687, 0], [63162, 0], [64092, 0], [64437, 0], [63586, 0], [66640, 0], [64288, 0], [65312, 0], [65854, 0], [65096, 0], [64008, 0], [65445, 0], [63810, 0], [61755, 0], [64543, 0], [65656, 0], [62392, 0], [66230, 0], [64809, 0], [64493, 0], [64096, 0], [64631, 0], [65792, 0], [63388, 0], [68114, 0], [68089, 0], [62941, 0], [76261, 0], [87632, 0], [86038, 0], [86906, 0], [89448, 0], [92570, 0], [85207, 0], [89488, 0], [86291, 0], [83881, 0], [85022, 0], [90250, 0], [83662, 0], [80026, 0], [83001, 0], [96922, 0], [84238, 0], [82813, 0], [85712, 0], [86341, 0], [83232, 0], [88381, 0], [86003, 0], [92664, 0], [87987, 0], [84368, 0], [85887, 0], [83633, 0], [83229, 0], [82245, 0], [89796, 0], [84409, 0], [86951, 0], [87653, 0], [88108, 0], [86902, 0], [92816, 0], [83965, 0], [84018, 0], [86526, 0], [85408, 0], [88507, 0], [92692, 0], [84995, 0], [87878, 0], [87470, 0], [90151, 0], [75704, 0], [61218, 0], [62723, 0], [63303, 0], [65261, 0], [60636, 0], [63934, 0], [63976, 0], [63850, 0], [63694, 0], [63943, 0], [61355, 0], [61234, 0], [59433, 0], [63056, 0], [63843, 0], [61684, 0], [66048, 0], [64672, 0], [62479, 0], [64313, 0], [64928, 0], [61349, 0], [62406, 0], [58736, 0], [63421, 0], [62475, 0], [62517, 0], [62563, 0], [64837, 0], [61525, 0], [64306, 0], [64519, 0], [65560, 0], [66356, 0], [61136, 0], [63738, 0], [63280, 0], [62877, 0], [62154, 0], [61707, 0], [67052, 1], [74233, 1], [72623, 1], [74508, 1], [67562, 1], [72229, 1], [67851, 1], [67511, 1], [69248, 1], [74974, 1], [74187, 1], [72957, 1], [67944, 1], [68135, 1], [71545, 1], [67474, 1], [71453, 1], [67825, 1], [69856, 1], [65070, 1], [69639, 1], [69216, 1], [66005, 1], [69755, 1], [73428, 1], [71655, 1], [71099, 1], [67011, 1], [67084, 1], [70827, 1], [69626, 1], [70992, 1], [68670, 1], [73347, 1], [67745, 1], [75339, 1], [66678, 1], [68835, 1], [67432, 1], [68697, 1], [70005, 1], [68589, 1], [70043, 1], [73081, 1], [66752, 1], [64527, 1], [67681, 1], [65263, 1], [73528, 1], [69567, 1], [69424, 1], [68622, 1], [66777, 1], [65736, 1], [70269, 1], [70602, 1], [72541, 1], [74773, 1], [75853, 1], [88819, 1], [88197, 1], [90929, 1], [85980, 1], [94400, 1], [87922, 1], [89188, 1], [88460, 1], [92828, 1], [92395, 1], [84856, 1], [90260, 1], [100270, 1], [90583, 1], [96696, 1], [88046, 1], [89645, 1], [82733, 1], [86277, 1], [91142, 1], [79295, 1], [95406, 1], [80258, 1], [81773, 1], [93251, 1], [90475, 1], [85782, 1], [85316, 1], [81187, 1], [90214, 1], [87218, 1], [84642, 1], [90884, 1], [89160, 1], [85979, 1], [91559, 1], [88694, 1], [89074, 1], [86838, 1], [86119, 1], [88569, 1], [89876, 1], [90645, 1], [96815, 1], [88216, 1], [88822, 1], [86366, 1], [92094, 1], [87245, 1], [84651, 1], [86578, 1], [81661, 1], [91814, 1], [81212, 1], [91808, 1], [85967, 1], [86156, 1], [87551, 1], [89016, 1], [83845, 1], [84126, 1], [90127, 1], [85890, 1], [84217, 1], [82763, 1], [93187, 1], [92965, 1], [88958, 1], [88778, 1], [89774, 1], [89140, 1], [93618, 1], [85944, 1], [83575, 1], [87410, 1], [89645, 1], [87745, 1], [86220, 1], [86243, 1], [89512, 1], [84920, 1], [89664, 1], [90759, 1], [81332, 1], [90946, 1], [89405, 1], [84306, 1], [92051, 1], [80420, 1], [85887, 1], [96523, 1], [85732, 1], [91507, 1], [88033, 1], [90741, 1], [85379, 1], [89795, 1], [90433, 1], [87067, 1], [89758, 1], [87392, 1], [99004, 1], [79976, 1], [96251, 1], [80520, 1], [83955, 1], [91186, 1], [86748, 1], [92260, 1], [86786, 1], [82938, 1], [89686, 1], [87126, 1], [89578, 1], [87403, 1], [90847, 1], [89691, 1], [85924, 1], [85618, 1], [83991, 1], [84521, 1], [82558, 1], [88047, 1], [81808, 1], [87109, 1], [85480, 1], [88000, 1], [89152, 1], [83069, 1], [90541, 1], [84351, 1], [87541, 1], [86845, 1], [90766, 1], [89529, 1], [90141, 1], [79068, 1], [87132, 1], [90289, 1], [90651, 1], [86041, 1], [60113, 2], [59063, 2], [61852, 2], [60645, 2], [63143, 2], [61374, 2], [65586, 2], [67208, 2], [62106, 2], [64986, 2], [60953, 2], [61091, 2], [64868, 2], [62052, 2], [58914, 2], [56172, 2], [59736, 2], [62173, 2], [64465, 2], [59648, 2], [58878, 2], [60084, 2], [63734, 2], [63381, 2], [61178, 2], [57658, 2], [59034, 2], [59266, 2], [59033, 2], [61484, 2], [62872, 2], [63041, 2], [62193, 2], [64685, 2], [64550, 2], [70765, 2], [70958, 2], [73657, 2], [75166, 2], [76840, 2], [76641, 2], [79398, 2], [74909, 2], [80133, 2], [75695, 2], [81012, 2], [75984, 2], [80409, 2], [76834, 2], [76414, 2], [70842, 2], [80121, 2], [77201, 2], [72139, 2], [72176, 2], [77479, 2], [71461, 2], [78102, 2], [77739, 2], [74382, 2], [73915, 2], [74632, 2], [78661, 2], [72981, 2], [74161, 2], [76198, 2], [75268, 2], [79977, 2], [75564, 2], [78685, 2], [67757, 2], [69389, 2], [75523, 2], [73753, 2], [68451, 2], [76509, 2], [72928, 2], [73425, 2], [75258, 2], [68694, 2], [72763, 2], [78820, 2], [75895, 2], [74653, 2], [76672, 2], [78822, 2], [71993, 2], [69836, 2], [69097, 2], [69807, 2], [71270, 2], [73221, 2], [70913, 2], [72627, 2], [70012, 2], [65297, 2], [71572, 2], [70351, 2], [70637, 2], [67153, 2], [70597, 2], [70467, 2], [70232, 2], [72093, 2], [70878, 2], [67655, 2], [72415, 2], [72455, 2], [69909, 2], [72167, 2], [71025, 2], [70466, 2], [74187, 2], [75034, 2], [68641, 2], [71964, 2], [65173, 2], [68874, 2], [70097, 2], [72032, 2], [70211, 2], [69356, 2], [68623, 2], [71929, 2], [76769, 2], [74126, 2], [69742, 2], [67388, 2], [68369, 2], [68634, 2], [64308, 2], [67660, 2], [70305, 2], [68906, 2], [71956, 2], [69702, 2], [71975, 2], [70039, 2], [71200, 2], [73100, 2], [69235, 2], [68273, 2], [73474, 2], [74098, 2], [72506, 2], [72266, 2], [71425, 2], [69528, 2], [76053, 2], [71974, 2], [71721, 2], [67440, 2], [72309, 2], [71713, 2], [77687, 2], [69926, 2], [74179, 2], [78254, 2], [74404, 2], [67881, 2], [70171, 2], [67938, 2], [75373, 2], [67294, 2], [71006, 2], [70359, 2], [65818, 2], [66857, 2], [72976, 2], [67315, 2], [67065, 2], [68757, 2], [65519, 2], [63333, 2], [66712, 2], [63309, 2], [61785, 2], [66554, 2], [66460, 2], [65430, 2], [66224, 2], [66408, 2], [65732, 2], [64310, 2], [64600, 2], [66423, 2], [62622, 2], [63647, 2], [67408, 2], [63189, 2], [63687, 2], [64928, 2], [63631, 2], [62951, 2], [65249, 2], [66913, 2], [64230, 2], [68404, 2], [65972, 2], [64964, 2], [66675, 3], [67493, 3], [68211, 3], [68208, 3], [66947, 3], [66672, 3], [67179, 3], [64600, 3], [66755, 3], [67838, 3], [62115, 3], [64571, 3], [64534, 3], [64303, 3], [67973, 3], [64633, 3], [67636, 3], [65273, 3], [66224, 3], [63728, 3], [64871, 3], [65506, 3], [65842, 3], [67872, 3], [66396, 3], [67993, 3], [65575, 3], [63952, 3], [63273, 3], [65299, 3], [67330, 3], [62481, 3], [66616, 3], [70430, 3], [64963, 3], [64394, 3], [61821, 3], [64474, 3], [65745, 3], [67071, 3], [63272, 3], [63752, 3], [63473, 3], [62836, 3], [66163, 3], [67129, 3], [63989, 3], [66737, 3], [66388, 3], [66431, 3], [64805, 3], [61909, 3], [65669, 3], [66157, 3], [68233, 3], [64630, 3], [65679, 3], [62009, 3], [63256, 3], [65752, 3], [64391, 3], [68220, 3], [66426, 3], [64016, 3], [62914, 3], [66229, 3], [62680, 3], [63459, 3], [63854, 3], [64005, 3], [64109, 3], [66026, 3], [66969, 3], [65650, 3], [65411, 3], [64149, 3], [63205, 3], [64518, 3], [66544, 3], [66794, 3], [62582, 3], [67820, 3], [63952, 3], [64731, 3], [63617, 3], [64875, 3], [65808, 3], [64945, 3], [61852, 3], [64756, 3], [65313, 3], [64804, 3], [62262, 3], [68887, 3], [63449, 3], [68439, 3], [62754, 3], [62885, 3], [65166, 3], [62961, 3], [62748, 3], [65071, 3], [67089, 3], [65524, 3], [63206, 3], [64093, 3], [62675, 3], [66558, 3], [64204, 3], [61028, 3], [64355, 3], [66496, 3], [63135, 3], [63742, 3], [66572, 3], [61789, 3], [85010, 3], [80105, 3], [73694, 3], [79658, 3], [79775, 3], [80407, 3], [75298, 3], [78664, 3], [81786, 3], [77535, 3], [74751, 3], [79177, 3], [81680, 3], [78655, 3], [80353, 3], [80889, 3], [85804, 3], [83034, 3], [81710, 3], [81669, 3], [81199, 3], [78301, 3], [90484, 3], [79032, 3], [80956, 3], [80832, 3], [83431, 3], [82302, 3], [80979, 3], [80754, 3], [84929, 3], [84837, 3], [85235, 3], [81712, 3], [84189, 3], [81486, 3], [81015, 3], [81899, 3], [77373, 3], [84663, 3], [81721, 3], [78474, 3], [80739, 3], [76807, 3], [77778, 3], [76944, 3], [77429, 3], [82684, 3], [80756, 3], [78033, 3], [81831, 3], [79288, 3], [78275, 3], [81673, 3], [79177, 3], [76272, 3], [78992, 3], [82028, 3], [82507, 3], [86826, 3], [82914, 3], [79892, 3], [78144, 3], [83059, 3], [83682, 3], [88096, 3], [83166, 3], [80594, 3], [84159, 3], [81368, 3], [85706, 3], [78368, 3], [81721, 3], [79974, 3], [77458, 3], [81984, 3], [82622, 3], [80240, 3], [84334, 3], [82594, 3], [79293, 3], [83670, 3], [78894, 3], [81988, 3]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 4)
labels = "good", "medium", "bad", "good"
for (_, group), a, l in zip(df.groupby(1), ax, labels):
    a.plot(group[0], label = l)
    a.legend(loc = "upper left")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do an FFT; the sharper the transition in the time domain, the more energy will occupy the higher frequency portion of the FFT (which will be in the middle of the typical FFT output). I believe this is how some auto-focus algorithms work.

Comment: I might also suggest trying the Total Variation Denoising approach. Will post an answer later.

Comment: @jojek Looking forward to your post!

Comment: @jojek Yeah, that would definitely be interesting to see but in this particular case, I would be wary of the optimisation step in TVM which might result in higher computational complexity per waveform. Komodovaran_, do you understand how a metric (a single number) is derived by the histogram as mentioned further below?

Answer (score 2):

One of the quickest things you can do is obtain the histogram of the sequence and assess how close it is to a [bimodal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution) distribution.

Waveforms with relatively large "linear" portions at different levels will be appearing as two distinct peaks in the histogram (1, 4 in your examples).

Waveforms where the transition is smooth between the two levels will have more values "spread" between the two peaks (2,3 in your examples).

This histogram representation will allow you to create various metrics too. So, for example, you can form a metric of the "amount of waveform" that exists between two maxima of the histogram divided by the "distance" between the two maxima in the histogram. This is one number. The lower this number is the closer your waveform is to the pattern you are looking for.

This can also be extended to more than one levels or asymmetries between the two maxima which would cover your first example. These asymmetries point to "pulses" that may be shorter with respect to the whole waveform. Presumably you can quantify these durations through knowledge of the system that produces these signals (?).

Here is a quick example in [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/):

```
Fs=1000; %Sampling frequency in Hz
T=1; % Signal duration in seconds
t=0:(1./Fs):(T-(1./Fs));
p=2*pi*t;
s=square(p)+random("normal", 0,0.001,1,length(p));
plot(s);grid on;xlabel("Time(Samples)");ylabel("Amplitude");
hist(s,100)
```

The ideal case:

[image]

[image]

Notice here, the "distance" between the two peaks is 2 and the "amount of waveform" (or in other words, counts of intermediate values between these two extremal values) is zero.

A less than ideal case of "spillage" of signal values in the intermediate region between the two maxima:

[image]

[image]

In this case, the distance between the maxima will still be 2 (theoretically) but now we have "more waveform" between these two values so our metric will be more elevated. I write "theoretically" because if you try to locate the maxima with an automated way you might not spot the exact maximum because of the blurring of that value that is caused by the noise process.

Here, the severity of the "spillage" is controlled by the standard deviation of the random number generator in the `random` function. This is `0.001` in the ideal and 0.6 in the less than ideal cases respectively. In Octave, `random` is part of the statistics package and `square` is part of the signal processing package which you will also need to install for this to work.

The signals you provide seem to have the same dynamic range, which is good from a detection point of view. If the signals are such that the dynamic range might be different from one signal to another, then you can still use this method but derive the metric on percentages rather than absolute counts.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Dan Boschen points out a potential limitation with the suggested way of quantifying the waveforms.

The OP mentions "squareness" but only 1/4 of the examples is square. The rest of the examples are clearly steps. We also do not know anything more about the SNR or anything else about the systems that generate these signals.

The main idea here is that the signal, in an accepted waveform, swings between two states. In the ideal case it clearly swings between two numbers, say for instance 2 and 8. These two numbers will appear in the histogram as two peaks. By putting some limits around the maxima and their in-between values, you can get a (fast) metric of the waveform's proximity to this "ideal" waveform.

If the amplitude of the signal happens to change (which is not what is hapenning here), you simply divide the histogram bins by the sum of the histogram and you work with percentages, but still trying to evaluate "peakiness and spread" (of the histogram). (This is also mentioned earlier).

The histogram is created in one-pass and therefore has a low computational cost.

In the case of soft waveforms:

```
x=-10:0.1:10;
s=zeros(1,length(x));
s=(1./(1+exp(-x))) + random("normal",0,0.001,1,length(g));
```

*Soft*

[image]

*Hard*

[image]

**Shifted**

Substitute the function's domain with `x=-13:0.1:7;`

*Soft*

[image]

*Hard*

(A better case anyway, from the point of view of detection)

[image]

**Shifted and noisy**

*Soft*

[image]

*Hard*

[image]

**Degenerate cases**

(i.e. too much shifting or other distortions that deviate a lot from the "squareness")

[image]

The function's domain here is `x=-18:0.1:2;`

[image]

The slope of the sigmoidal here is 0.5;

And in the case of pulse-like signals

```
%For this snippet, need to recreate n,s upon changing either of preoffset,postoffset,plen.
x=-10:0.1:10;
p=(1./(1+exp(-x)));
preoffset=100;
postoffset=20;
plen=1;
n=random("normal",0,0.001,1,preoffset+postoffset+plen+2*length(p));
s=[zeros(1,preoffset),p,ones(1,plen),p(end:-1:1),zeros(1,postoffset)] + n;
subplot(121);plot(s);grid on;subplot(122);hist(s,100);grid on;
```

*Soft*

[image]

*Hard Shifted and Noisy*

`preoffset=144,postoffset=20,plen=11`, sigmoidal slope to 8, noise deviation to 0.1. (To approximate the first provided example).

[image]

*Soft relatively short and noisy*

`preoffset=1000, plen=1;postoffset=200;`, sigmoidal slope to 1, noise standard deviation to 0.1

[image]

This reveals a problem here where two maximal peaks of the "low state" are very near but you can overcome this by setting a minimum limit to the distance between two peaks (again a very inexpensive operation).

Comment: I think the problem with this approach is that it depends very much on time span between the transitions which doesn't really have anything to do with the "squareness". This is clear if you consider a very long time span relative to the transition (meaning few transitions). The historgram given the time spent in each area (low vs high) will still be quite bimodal.  The "Squareness" verification that I think makes most sense is something that would access the rise/fall time directly. (such as the frequency content with FFT as I mentioned, or perhaps other time based methods?)

Comment: @DanBoschen Thank you for the note. I added some more plots with soft waveforms and the snippet that generated them. I have selected some parameters arbitrarily for these plots, hopefully in a non-biased way :) But it gives some space for experimentation in the absence of any more specifications. You are right about the "squariness" though, which I interpreted as "stepness" because of examples 2,3,4 which are not "pulse like". You want the histogram to be bimodal but the relative time spent in the states will modulate its peaks.

Comment: Nice plots. Given the same time span and number of transitions it works well and is conveniently simple to do (standard deviation around each peak). Where I think it wouldn’t apply is comparing cases of very different time spans and number of transitions (if “squareness” is indeed meant to be in terms of absolute time such as rise time). Unless the rate of transitions is the same in the cases compared in which case it would be time span independent.

Comment: It wouldn’t be unreasonable to constrain the algorithm to the same time span and one transition in both sets with the transition centered in the capture, in which case your algorithm should be quite robust.

Comment: After reading the answers and learning, perhaps I should've named the issue "how  to determine the step-function-ness of a time series?"

Answer (score 0):

What about using a moving average filter? This would smooth the curves to spot the 'squareness' more easily. For example, with this code (the efficient solution for the MA was taken from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728392/moving-average-or-running-mean)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[70872, 65951, 66453, 69058, 67483, 69352, 66139, 66042, 65832, 62785, 66679, 66407, 65364, 67065, 62789, 63566, 62788, 63823, 66169, 62814, 64090, 66121, 66147, 61734, 64699, 66599, 64997, 63778, 62466, 62359, 68352, 66454, 65818, 64873, 67705, 64548, 65268, 66382, 63212, 67100, 64943, 64848, 64757, 64170, 65676, 65108, 66865, 62515, 62498, 64160, 65965, 67430, 67520, 63422, 62874, 62442, 62699, 61413, 63993, 65945, 63927, 65711, 68361, 65237, 65791, 63750, 62580, 64105, 63556, 62507, 65663, 63952, 66916, 62010, 64337, 65831, 65555, 64249, 62909, 62050, 63368, 63323, 64340, 66999, 65624, 64687, 63162, 64092, 64437, 63586, 66640, 64288, 65312, 65854, 65096, 64008, 65445, 63810, 61755, 64543, 65656, 62392, 66230, 64809, 64493, 64096, 64631, 65792, 63388, 68114, 68089, 62941, 76261, 87632, 86038, 86906, 89448, 92570, 85207, 89488, 86291, 83881, 85022, 90250, 83662, 80026, 83001, 96922, 84238, 82813, 85712, 86341, 83232, 88381, 86003, 92664, 87987, 84368, 85887, 83633, 83229, 82245, 89796, 84409, 86951, 87653, 88108, 86902, 92816, 83965, 84018, 86526, 85408, 88507, 92692, 84995, 87878, 87470, 90151, 75704, 61218, 62723, 63303, 65261, 60636, 63934, 63976, 63850, 63694, 63943, 61355, 61234, 59433, 63056, 63843, 61684, 66048, 64672, 62479, 64313, 64928, 61349, 62406, 58736, 63421, 62475, 62517, 62563, 64837, 61525, 64306, 64519, 65560, 66356, 61136, 63738, 63280, 62877, 62154, 61707],
                   [67052, 74233, 72623, 74508, 67562, 72229, 67851, 67511, 69248, 74974, 74187, 72957, 67944, 68135, 71545, 67474, 71453, 67825, 69856, 65070, 69639, 69216, 66005, 69755, 73428, 71655, 71099, 67011, 67084, 70827, 69626, 70992, 68670, 73347, 67745, 75339, 66678, 68835, 67432, 68697, 70005, 68589, 70043, 73081, 66752, 64527, 67681, 65263, 73528, 69567, 69424, 68622, 66777, 65736, 70269, 70602, 72541, 74773, 75853, 88819, 88197, 90929, 85980, 94400, 87922, 89188, 88460, 92828, 92395, 84856, 90260, 100270, 90583, 96696, 88046, 89645, 82733, 86277, 91142, 79295, 95406, 80258, 81773, 93251, 90475, 85782, 85316, 81187, 90214, 87218, 84642, 90884, 89160, 85979, 91559, 88694, 89074, 86838, 86119, 88569, 89876, 90645, 96815, 88216, 88822, 86366, 92094, 87245, 84651, 86578, 81661, 91814, 81212, 91808, 85967, 86156, 87551, 89016, 83845, 84126, 90127, 85890, 84217, 82763, 93187, 92965, 88958, 88778, 89774, 89140, 93618, 85944, 83575, 87410, 89645, 87745, 86220, 86243, 89512, 84920, 89664, 90759, 81332, 90946, 89405, 84306, 92051, 80420, 85887, 96523, 85732, 91507, 88033, 90741, 85379, 89795, 90433, 87067, 89758, 87392, 99004, 79976, 96251, 80520, 83955, 91186, 86748, 92260, 86786, 82938, 89686, 87126, 89578, 87403, 90847, 89691, 85924, 85618, 83991, 84521, 82558, 88047, 81808, 87109, 85480, 88000, 89152, 83069, 90541, 84351, 87541, 86845, 90766, 89529, 90141, 79068, 87132, 90289, 90651, 86041],
                   [60113, 59063, 61852, 60645, 63143, 61374, 65586, 67208, 62106, 64986, 60953, 61091, 64868, 62052, 58914, 56172, 59736, 62173, 64465, 59648, 58878, 60084, 63734, 63381, 61178, 57658, 59034, 59266, 59033, 61484, 62872, 63041, 62193, 64685, 64550, 70765, 70958, 73657, 75166, 76840, 76641, 79398, 74909, 80133, 75695, 81012, 75984, 80409, 76834, 76414, 70842, 80121, 77201, 72139, 72176, 77479, 71461, 78102, 77739, 74382, 73915, 74632, 78661, 72981, 74161, 76198, 75268, 79977, 75564, 78685, 67757, 69389, 75523, 73753, 68451, 76509, 72928, 73425, 75258, 68694, 72763, 78820, 75895, 74653, 76672, 78822, 71993, 69836, 69097, 69807, 71270, 73221, 70913, 72627, 70012, 65297, 71572, 70351, 70637, 67153, 70597, 70467, 70232, 72093, 70878, 67655, 72415, 72455, 69909, 72167, 71025, 70466, 74187, 75034, 68641, 71964, 65173, 68874, 70097, 72032, 70211, 69356, 68623, 71929, 76769, 74126, 69742, 67388, 68369, 68634, 64308, 67660, 70305, 68906, 71956, 69702, 71975, 70039, 71200, 73100, 69235, 68273, 73474, 74098, 72506, 72266, 71425, 69528, 76053, 71974, 71721, 67440, 72309, 71713, 77687, 69926, 74179, 78254, 74404, 67881, 70171, 67938, 75373, 67294, 71006, 70359, 65818, 66857, 72976, 67315, 67065, 68757, 65519, 63333, 66712, 63309, 61785, 66554, 66460, 65430, 66224, 66408, 65732, 64310, 64600, 66423, 62622, 63647, 67408, 63189, 63687, 64928, 63631, 62951, 65249, 66913, 64230, 68404, 65972, 64964],
                   [66675, 67493, 68211, 68208, 66947, 66672, 67179, 64600, 66755, 67838, 62115, 64571, 64534, 64303, 67973, 64633, 67636, 65273, 66224, 63728, 64871, 65506, 65842, 67872, 66396, 67993, 65575, 63952, 63273, 65299, 67330, 62481, 66616, 70430, 64963, 64394, 61821, 64474, 65745, 67071, 63272, 63752, 63473, 62836, 66163, 67129, 63989, 66737, 66388, 66431, 64805, 61909, 65669, 66157, 68233, 64630, 65679, 62009, 63256, 65752, 64391, 68220, 66426, 64016, 62914, 66229, 62680, 63459, 63854, 64005, 64109, 66026, 66969, 65650, 65411, 64149, 63205, 64518, 66544, 66794, 62582, 67820, 63952, 64731, 63617, 64875, 65808, 64945, 61852, 64756, 65313, 64804, 62262, 68887, 63449, 68439, 62754, 62885, 65166, 62961, 62748, 65071, 67089, 65524, 63206, 64093, 62675, 66558, 64204, 61028, 64355, 66496, 63135, 63742, 66572, 61789, 85010, 80105, 73694, 79658, 79775, 80407, 75298, 78664, 81786, 77535, 74751, 79177, 81680, 78655, 80353, 80889, 85804, 83034, 81710, 81669, 81199, 78301, 90484, 79032, 80956, 80832, 83431, 82302, 80979, 80754, 84929, 84837, 85235, 81712, 84189, 81486, 81015, 81899, 77373, 84663, 81721, 78474, 80739, 76807, 77778, 76944, 77429, 82684, 80756, 78033, 81831, 79288, 78275, 81673, 79177, 76272, 78992, 82028, 82507, 86826, 82914, 79892, 78144, 83059, 83682, 88096, 83166, 80594, 84159, 81368, 85706, 78368, 81721, 79974, 77458, 81984, 82622, 80240, 84334, 82594, 79293, 83670, 78894, 81988]])

N = 5

def running_mean(x, N):
    cumsum = np.cumsum(np.insert(x, 0, 0)) 
    return (cumsum[N:] - cumsum[:-N]) / float(N)

means = [running_mean(x, N) for x in data]

plt.figure(1)
for i in range(len(data)):
    plt.subplot(411 + i)
    plt.plot(data[i])
    plt.plot([None] * (len(data[i]) - len(means[i])) + means[i].tolist())

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

You get something like this:

[image]

I'm not really sure if this is what you are looking for (I didn't understand from your question if you just want to be able to spot easier the quality of the signals or if some automatic solution with no human interaction should be found) but I think it can help.

Comment: This is not a very quantitative solution though. Then I'd have to manually decide whether I find it square or not (which I'd rather not. I'll specify in main post).